# Next.js with Express Backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I have a next.js application that runs with an express server. Everything was fine until the fetch. When I send from front-end to back-end post request, it works fine. And also when I try to fetch some data from another server it works fine. But whenever I want to fetch data from my server(same server as next app), it does not fetch. When I go to the page through the client(routes) it fetches everything, when I refresh and try (server side) does not work... When I console log the data inside `getInitialProps` it shows on the terminal(server). The error occurs only when I try to fetch something from my server.

Here is my server :

```
const app = next({ dev });

const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();
  server.use(bodyparser.json());
  server.use(cors());

  server.use("/api", userRoutes);
  server.get("/service/:slug", (req, res) => {
    return app.render(req, res, "/service", { slug: req.params.slug });
  });
  server.get("*", (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

And this is service page:

```
import fetch from "isomorphic-fetch";
import Layout from "../components/layout";

const Service = ({ data }) => {
  console.log(data,'ins');
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div style={{ padding: "100px" }} className="componentDiv">
        <p>xxx</p>
        {/* <p>{json.longDesc}</p>
        <img src={json.img} alt="" /> */}
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

Service.getInitialProps = async ({ query }) => {
  const response = await fetch(
    `http://localhost:3000/api/service/${query.slug}`
  );
  const jsonv = await response.json();
  console.log(jsonv);
  return { data: jsonv.data };
};

export default Service;
```

Update!

I used axios instead isomorphic fetch and problem solved.

Comment: Where is `port` defined in the server ? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: @conradkdotcom I didn't put all the file it's long file, everything works correctly normally. I can make post requests to server successfully. The only problem is fetching doesn't work for server side..

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you see any error messages? If so, which are they?

Comment: It says undefined, doesn't fetch anything.

Comment: @TahaA. I have the same problem. have you found a way yet?

Comment: @SobhanJahanmard I used axios instead isomorphic fetch and problem solved.